# Why do batches of larger files get processed faster than same-sized batches of smaller files?

Tags: xml, performance, dom, vb6, xdoc

Does it make sense that a VB6 program that processes ~50,000 xml files runs about 3x faster [in terms of number of files processed per second] if the files are each about 30KB in size, than if the files are each about 4KB in size?  If it does make sense, how can I speed up processing of the smaller files?

The program reads each file, computes an MD5 hash value for the file and calls a SQL Server stored procedure to see if a version of the file having the same hash value is already stored in a database.  If the file's computed hash value is already stored in the database the file isn't processed further; the program just repeats with the next file.

I've been testing on batches of ~50,000 xml files that have already been processed into the database, so the program just loops: get the next xml file<kbd>→</kbd>hash it<kbd>→</kbd>call Sproc<kbd>→</kbd>repeat.

I expected the program to run faster on similar-sized batches of smaller files, but it's significantly slower.

The program runs on a 64-bit Windows 10 workstation.  The files are stored in a single directory on the workstation's C:\ drive (which is an SSD).  SQL Server runs on a VM under Windows Server.

**EDIT:**
I think I have found the bottleneck, but I don't know how to solve it.  The relevant piece of code is below.  The bottleneck is caused by the `xDOC.async = False` statement.  If I remove it I get an immediate 20x speed improvement.  **BUT** removing it causes document load failure errors since the code apparently can't handle asynchronous file loading.  Can this be speeded up?

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim xDOC As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xPE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\These are my XML Files")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    Set xDOC = New DOMDocument
    xDOC.async = False    ("THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM")

    If xDOC.Load(objFile.Path) Then

        /* process the file */

    Else
        Set xPE = xDOC.parseError
        With xPE
            /* set up objFile.Name failed to load error message */
        End With
            /* log error details */
        Set xPE = Nothing
    End If

    Set xDOC = Nothing

Next objFile
```

Comment: Where is the time difference? In the reading, hashing or db call?

Comment: The system has a better chance to predict file access patterns the larger the file is. An XML parser will generally access the file in sequential order, a pattern the system is well prepared to optimize. By the time new data is requested it has been read into memory already with high probability. As far as I know, the system cannot optimize disk access across different files. For lots of small files you're going to observe the worst case performance.

Comment: The program is probably not parsing the file if it is doing an MD5 hash.  A 4K file should be faster to read and run a hash on than a 30K file.  If there are the same number of files then I don't think it would run slower.  Now if it was the same amount of data, but split into many more smaller files then I may agree.  Anyway, BRW you will need to show some code, because otherwise we are all just guessing.

Comment: The program parses the XML, but only if the SProc's hash comparison indicates that the same version of the XML file isn't already stored in the database; otherwise there's no need to re-parse the same version of the file.  I'll do some further tests as suggested by Alex K and report back.

Comment: In regards to async, you didn't really see a 20x improvement, you are allowing your code to continue **before** the XML doc is fully parsed (it will happen in background).  That's not apples to apples.

Comment: @tcarvin  I take your point.  I am also beginning to doubt that I really have have found the bottleneck.  For all I know the culprit is something else entirely like missing or improperly configured database indexes.  Maybe I should just delete this question (since it may just be misleading people), do a whole lot of further testing and experimentation, and then perhaps post a different question unless I manage to figure things out on my own.  I certainly appreciate everyone's comments thus far.